# iMessage effects with Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation, rive

Does anyone know if there are any pre-made packages for effects like the ones in iMessage?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfAPip-QtTc

I'm specifically looking for something along the lines of the confetti or balloon effect (but with hearts)

If there are no pre-made package, what would be the best way to go about making something like this (as an overlay). Would it be easy to do natively or use something like Rive (https://rive.app/)

Thanks!